# eclipse generated jar file gives "Error: Could not find or load main class" on Linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, jar

I generated an runnable jar file with eclipse.

On Windows i have no problems executing it, but on Linux i get an `Error: Could not find or load main class application.Main`

I am using Apache CLI and JavaFX with export settings: `Extract required libraries into generated JAR`

### **Tree**

```
JAR
│   jfx8.cssext
│   about.html
│
├───META-INF
│   │   MANIFEST.MF
│   │   ECLIPSE_.RSA
│   │   LICENSE.txt
│   │   NOTICE.txt
│   │
│   └───maven
│       └───commons-cli
│           └───commons-cli
│                   pom.xml
│                   pom.properties
│
├───application
│       DragonCurve.class
│       Expression$1.class
│       Expression$10.class
│       Expression$11.class
│       Expression$12.class
│       Expression$13.class
│       Expression$14.class
│       Expression$15.class
│       Expression$16.class
│       Expression$17.class
│       Expression$18.class
│       Expression$19.class
│       Expression$2.class
│       Expression$20.class
│       Expression$21.class
│       Expression$22.class
│       Expression$23.class
│       Expression$24.class
│       Expression$25.class
│       Expression$26.class
│       Expression$27.class
│       Expression$28.class
│       Expression$29.class
│       Expression$3.class
│       Expression$30.class
│       Expression$31.class
│       Expression$32.class
│       Expression$33.class
│       Expression$34.class
│       Expression$35.class
│       Expression$36.class
│       Expression$37.class
│       Expression$38.class
│       Expression$39.class
│       Expression$4.class
│       Expression$40.class
│       Expression$41.class
│       Expression$42.class
│       Expression$43.class
│       Expression$5.class
│       Expression$6.class
│       Expression$7.class
│       Expression$8.class
│       Expression$9.class
│       Expression$ExpressionException.class
│       Expression$Function$1.class
│       Expression$Function.class
│       Expression$LazyFunction.class
│       Expression$LazyNumber.class
│       Expression$Operator.class
│       Expression$Tokenizer.class
│       Expression.class
│       Main$ColorType.class
│       Main.class
│       application.css
│
└───org
    └───apache
        └───commons
            └───cli
                    AlreadySelectedException.class
                    AmbiguousOptionException.class
                    BasicParser.class
                    CommandLine.class
                    CommandLineParser.class
                    DefaultParser.class
                    GnuParser.class
                    HelpFormatter$1.class
                    HelpFormatter$OptionComparator.class
                    HelpFormatter.class
                    MissingArgumentException.class
                    MissingOptionException.class
                    Option$1.class
                    Option$Builder.class
                    Option.class
                    OptionBuilder.class
                    OptionGroup.class
                    Options.class
                    OptionValidator.class
                    ParseException.class
                    Parser.class
                    PatternOptionBuilder.class
                    PosixParser.class
                    TypeHandler.class
                    UnrecognizedOptionException.class
                    Util.class
```

### MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: application.Main

Name: about.html
SHA-256-Digest: 1fuYr0bu6NsJZCAmSom5QtnvnV0Cg8DwLn77Dd1Ql24=

Name: jfx8.cssext
SHA-256-Digest: b2p9PXeoxqnTdYgBFeKp3s7J9PajukOS3sGqyM4s36I=
```

I tried executing with `java -jar myjar.jar`, `java -cp myjar.jar application.Main` and got `Error: Could not find or load main class`

Comment: try dos2unix MANIFEST.MF

Comment: What distribution are you using? Many Linux distros pack JavaFX to a different package, so you may not have it installed.

Comment: @sillyfly i am trying to execut it on rasberian

Comment: Do you have the package `openjfx` installed?

Comment: `java -cp myjar.jar application.Main` failing implies that the problem is not in finding the class, but in loading it, as in there may be missing dependencies. Is that short error message all you're given?

Comment: `Error: Could not find or load main class application.Main`is all i get