# Jar on Raspbian: could not find or load main class; works on Windows

Tags: java, maven, javafx, jar, raspbian

So I have a JAVAFX Maven project developing with NetBeans IDE on a Windows 10 machine. Everytime I run the project in IDE, there is a `.jar`-file named `MYPROJECT-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` created. Running the project in IDE works fine. Running that `.jar`-file on this or another Windows 10 machine using `java -jar MYPROJECT-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` is working perfectly fine.

However, trying to run the jar on Raspbian fails. I dont have any other Linux-OS available to test if it works there.

When executing `java -jar MYPROJECT-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` on Raspbian, the error message is:
`error: could not find or load main class foo.bar.Main` (translated from german, not sure if the error message would be exactly the same in english, but looking at other SO-questions I guess this is the correct translation).

My `Main.java` has the correct package-declaration `package foo.bar;` and a correct main-function `public static void main(String args[])`. I can open the `.jar`-file with a program like winrar and see that in directory `foo/bar/` there is the file `Main.class` and in directory `META-INF/` there is a file called `MANIFEST.MF` with content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Permissions: sandbox
JavaFX-Version: 8.0
Created-By: JavaFX Packager
Main-Class: foo.bar.Main
```

I am using some Libraries in the application, for example `com.google.gson`, but in the `.jar` there is the directory `com/google/gson/` with the corresponding `.class`-files. I dont think that this could be a source for this error, could it?

I realize that there are many other SO-questions regarding exactly that error (`could not find or load main class`), but I was not able to find a solution in these, or any similar case where it worked on Windows but not on Linux with these conditions.

**So my question is: why does this error occur and how can I fix it?**

On the Windows machines I tested it, I used Windows 10 with latest Java installed (1.8.0_121, worked with JDK installed as well as without JDK installed). On the Raspbian it is 1.8.0_65, but trying to update it says `oracle-java8-jdk is already the newest version` (again translated, maybe ). At this point I did everything I could think of, please help

Comment: so if you copy the jar file into another windows machines, does it still work? my best guess is that your libraries are outside ur jar files

Comment: @nafas Yes, I did exactly that and it worked. As far as I can see all libraries I am using are included in the jar file.

Comment: have you tried to actually build ur jar file inside a pi?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145576/eclipse-generated-jar-file-gives-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-on-l) - do you have the `openjfx` package installed?

Comment: @nafas I have not done that since I am developing on a Windows machine. I guess I can try that.

Comment: @Sebu I normally write the code and create build.xml to compile with ant anywhere that I plan to run the code.  might not be the most secure way but as long as the server(ur case pi) is secure then its fine

Comment: @sillyfly not that I know of. I guess I should get it on my Raspbian?

Comment: If you are using OpenJDK JRE then almost definitely, and it can't really hurt (unless you are extremely tight for space). You can verify which version you are using by running `java -version` in a terminal.

Comment: @sillyfly as I pointed out in my question, when running `java -version` I get `java version "1.8.0_65"`.I installed `openjfx` as described in [this](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_embedded). Now I am getting other error messages and the program starts, altough in a strange graphic mode where I can not use the mouse or see anything else. Even though your comment answered my question, I'm not really satisfied since my application is not running properly :(

Comment: @sillyfly I figured some more out, for example running with `sudo` in front fixes the mouse problem and the errors. Fullscreen apparently is the only way to run JFX on Raspbian. So my question is actually completely answered by your suggestion to install `openjfx`. If you post that as answer I will accept it